# Subset in R not removing rows in data frame

Tags: r, subset

To summarize the process, i pulled data from bbref, structured it in a data frame, converted 3 vectors to numeric from character, and took a subset of players who play greater than 20 games. Yet when i reorder the data and display the top 20, only a few non-qualifiers are removed and there are still many observations with less than 20 games played.

```r
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(plyr)

urladv <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_advanced.html"
urladvdata <-  getURL(urladv)
dataadv <- readHTMLTable(urladvdata, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
datadv <- structure(dataadv, row.names =c(NA, -734), .Names = seq_along(dataadv), class = "data.frame")
advstats <- ldply(dataadv, data.frame)
advstats[,c('PER', 'BPM')] <- sapply(advstats[,c('PER','BPM', 'G')], as.numeric)
advstats <- subset(advstats, G > 20)
advstats <- advstats[with(advstats,order(-PER)),]
advstats[1:20,]
```

The output of advstats[1:20,] includes players like Trevon Duval, Gary Payton, and Alan williams who each have 5 or under games played. I'm confused what the special case of these observations are since the subset removes over 100 observations.

Comment: Just FYI, if you have code written on the same line as the \`\`\` you used to mark off code, that tells the markdown parser that that text is the language to use, not a line of code. Until I added a new line, we couldn't see the url you're using

Comment: i appreciate the notice @camille

Comment: I think `subset` didn't do what you wanted for `G>20` since `G` was still a string and not numeric. For `sapply` are you missing `G` for assignment? Should be `advstats[,c('PER', 'BPM', 'G')] <- sapply(advstats[,c('PER','BPM', 'G')], as.numeric)`?

Comment: @Ben You're right, the G is missing. Including it fixes the subset behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Ben in the comments, you're missing `'G'` from the line that does `sapply()`. It should look like this:

```
advstats[,c('PER', 'BPM', 'G')] <- sapply(advstats[,c('PER','BPM', 'G')], as.numeric)
```

Because you were missing the `'G'` on the left-hand side of the `<-`, it hadn't converted `'G'` from `<chr>` to `<dbl>` data type. Therefore, when you ran the `subset()` function, it didn't work because you cannot use mathematical operators on character data types.

I trust that helps?